# Notify activity when IntentService completes - multiple activities

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, view, bundle, intentservice

Up to this point my **IntentService**(s) has been working great because each **IntentService** has only been receiving requests from a single **Activity** (SQLite INSERTs) and responding to the same **Activity**.

Then I figured out how to load **Views** in the **Activity** with data from the same **IntentService** (SQLite); now things are getting complicated. That is to say: I have at least *two Activities* making requests (READ/INSERT/UPDATE) to the same **IntentService** (an **IntentService** exists for each of 10 Tables in the SQLite Database).

**MAIN CHALLENGE:** The **IntentService** HAS TO KNOW *which Activity* an **Intent** came from and send responses (arrays of data OR result of an INSERT/UPDATE request from SQLite DB) back to the *CORRECT Activity*.

Up till now each **Activity** has been communicating with its **IntentService** using **Handler.Callback**, which now doesn't seem up to the task. The other two options are **ResultReceiver** and **LocalBroadcastManger**.

I need insight into the mechanism necessary for the **IntentService** to identify each **Intent**'s source/calling **Activity** so that responses/results go where they're supposed to go.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Quasaur, if you are committed to using an IntentService, I'm not sure there is much else outside of handlers and the other components you mentioned that you could use. However, IntentServices are designed to be a fire-and-forget kind of component, one that does not need to communicate back to its caller. If you need to do work in a service and communicate to callers directly, you are much better off binding to a regular Service.

From the documentation:
IntentService
This is a subclass of Service that uses a worker thread to handle all start requests, one at a time. This is the best option if you don't require that your service handle multiple requests simultaneously. All you need to do is implement onHandleIntent(), which receives the intent for each start request so you can do the background work.

Another issue that I see is your requirement to route responses to particular activities. You really should only have one activity at a time. Routing to more than one would suppose that you have more than one at a time which is problematic.

All that put to the side, if you are looking for a database abstraction layer, I recommend you look into the ContentProvider. It's a core component of Android that is used everywhere in the system. Documentation can be found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html

Keep in mind that ContentProviders are difficult to write by hand and even harder to write correctly. I gave a talk at our local Android developer meetup where I discussed a tool that is available for Eclipse that will generate them for you. It's changed the way I develop Android apps completely. Feel free to give it a look: https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=5LDXeRza_ak. I'm the second speaker.

Comment: Thank you so much, Grahambo, for that detailed answer.
I picked IntentService because of the queuing of requests. The user doesn't access more than one activity at a time and the service is only available to the app i'm writing.

Comment: I assume you're referring to this tool: [android-content-provider](http://code.google.com/p/mdsd-android-content-provider/)...can it look at an existing SQLite database and generate the content provider?

Comment: I don't believe it can at this time. It generates code based on a model declared by Eclipse EMF.